Wedge inside of itself math symbol
If we use \usepackage{amsmath} we get a symbol \Cap which, when rendered in math mode, produces an intersection symbol \cap inside an intersection symbol. How can we produce \Wedge for \wedge? (I.e., a wedge inside of a wedge.)

Another approach could be this looking the answer here importing the only symbol (rotated) $\ggg$ from mathabx package:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ggg}{\mathrel}{matha}{"CE}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\vg}{\mathbin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\ggg$}}}
\newcommand{\svg}{\scalebox{0.7}[0.8]{$\vg$}}
\begin{document}
The symbol rotated by $90^\circ$ is: \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\ggg$}. Using a new command...you will have:
\[\alpha \vg \beta \]
\[
\partial_x f= [2x \sin(y) + e^x]_{\svg} \iff A\vg B_{\svg}
\]

\end{document}

You can create also the other symbol rotating differently.

Addendum:
From boisik package you can take the symbol directly: the name is \Wedge.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bskadd}{U}{bskma}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{bskma}{\skewchar\font130 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bskma}{m}{n}{<->bskma10}{}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Wedge}{\mathbin}{bskadd}{"FC}
\begin{document}

\[\text{Computer modern font } f^\circ g= \alpha\Wedge \beta\]
\end{document}



I added similar code to my answer. Feel free to use it for your answer (and I'll remove it from mine). It should also be noted that the boisik fonts are only available in bitmap form.

@egreg Most Esteemed Prof. not deleted your answer. I will delete mine when the user will remove the green check mark.

Don't. Your answer is valuable, but could be improvemed. My suggestion of taking the code is still valid.

Not really pretty…
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Wedge}{\DOTSB\mathbin{\mathpalette\Wedge@\relax}}
\newcommand{\Wedge@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\wedge$\cr
    \hidewidth\scalebox{0.5}{\boldmath$\m@th#1\wedge$}\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \Wedge B$

$\scriptstyle A \Wedge B$

\end{document}


Before you ask, here's also \Vee.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Wedge}{\DOTSB\mathbin{\vphantom{\vee}\mathpalette\Wedge@\relax}}
\newcommand{\Wedge@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\wedge$\cr
    \hidewidth\scalebox{0.5}{\boldmath$\m@th#1\wedge$}\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\newcommand{\Vee}{\DOTSB\mathbin{\mathpalette\Vee@\relax}}
\newcommand{\Vee@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\vee$}%
  \ooalign{%
    \copy\z@\cr
    \hidewidth
    \raisebox{\dimeval{\ht\z@-\height}}{\scalebox{0.5}{\boldmath$\m@th#1\vee$}}%
    \hidewidth\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \Wedge B \Wedge \dots \Wedge C$

$\scriptstyle A \Wedge B$

$A \Vee B \Vee \dots \Vee C$

$\scriptstyle A \Vee B$

\end{document}


I also like Sebastiano's approach, which however needs a few improvements.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> matha5
  <5.5-6.5> matha6
  <6.5-7.5> matha7
  <7.5-8.5> matha8
  <8.5-9.5> matha9
  <9.5-11> matha10
  <11-> matha12
}{}

%%% helper command
\newcommand{\rotatewedgevee}[1]{%
  \nonscript{\mspace{-1mu}}\mspace{2mu}%
  \text{%
    \raisebox{0.89\depth}{%
      \rotatebox{-90}{\usefont{U}{matha}{m}{n}\symbol{#1}}%
    }%
  }%
  \nonscript{\mspace{-1mu}}\mspace{2mu}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Wedge}{}{\mathbin{\rotatewedgevee{"CE}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Vee}{}{\mathbin{\rotatewedgevee{"CF}}}

\begin{document}

$a \wedge a \Wedge a \Vee a \vee a$

$b \wedge b \Wedge b \Vee b \vee b$

$\scriptstyle a \wedge a \Wedge a \Vee a \vee a$

$\scriptstyle b \wedge b \Wedge b \Vee b \vee b$

\end{document}



Most Esteemed Professor. When there is respect, loyalty, fairness and sincerity I am always on His side. I don't know how it is translated into English but I hope it is clear. I am deleting my answer.

Prof. how I can deleted an accepted answer?

@John Hi. Excuse me for this comment: please remove the green check mark from my answer, and give it to egreg. Thank you very much.

There's always the TikZ option...

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, scalerel}

\newcommand{\Wedge}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\tikz{
    \path[use as bounding box](-.04,0)rectangle(.24,.23);
    \draw[line cap=round, line join=round, line width=.47pt](0,0)--(.1,.23)--(.2,0)(0.04,0)--(.1,.14)--(.16,0);}}{\wedge}
}}

\begin{document}

$A\wedge B$

$A\Wedge B$

\end{document}

